# Trouble creating a new record in Rails with Select Boxes and Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-console, rails-models

Ruby on Rails newbie here.

**TL;DR: When trying to create a new record, I get an error message saying my foreign keys must exist. I'm using Select Boxes on my view. Need help.**

I am creating a requests management system for our own support staff here in our company. So far, I have generated a scaffold for Issues and 2 models, one for Category and another for Subcategory.

So far, the relationship I came up with is designed like this:

Issue belongs to Category and Subcategory
Subcategory belongs to Category.

This means that a user may have a problem with his keyboard, for which he will create an Issue. This issues would belong the the subcategory named "Peripherals", which would in turn, belongs to a broader "Hardware" category.

I still need to implement Ajax to fetch data for my Select Boxes, but while testing it out in a simpler scenario, I couldn't create my Issues from the "New Issue" view. I come across an error message saying that Category and Subcategory must exist. I've reviewed what I've written so far, but couldn't find my mistake.

**Here is the code for my create method in the Issues controller**

```
def create
  @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @issue.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Issue was successfully created.' }        
    else
      @categories = Category.enabled
      @subcategories = Subcategory.enabled
      format.html { render :new }        
    end
  end
end
```

Here go my Models

**Issue Model:**

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

**Category Model:**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :issues

    enum status: { disabled: 0, enabled: 1 }

    after_initialize :set_defaults

  def self.enabled
    where(status: 'enabled')
  end

    def set_defaults
        self.status ||= 1
    end
end
```

**Subcategory Model**

```
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :issues

  enum status: { disabled: 0, enabled: 1 } 

  def self.enabled
    where(status: 'enabled')
  end

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.status ||= 1 
  end
end
```

**And finally, here are the parameters passed to the controller:**

```
Processing by IssuesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"tzKDayYfEbEwTaOFup/N9kQ+8tr9c0P5otV2B0boKGrgyv+HkQaEvYJ6ZMQeR+8XgCnhJR6PosVcx0jPJpqBEA==", "category_id"=>"1", "subcategory_id"=>"1", "issue"=>{"description"=>"Replace broken keyboard.", "status"=>"1", "criticality_level"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Issue"}
```

[I was able to create an Issue via Rails Console, though.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAnih.jpg)

Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify create action as follows

```
def create
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

  @issue = @category.issues.build(issue_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @issue.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Issue was successfully created.' }        
    else
      @categories = Category.enabled
      @subcategories = Subcategory.enabled
      format.html { render :new }        
    end
  end
end
```